# antivirus escaping from browser

Tags: anti-virus

till now i didnt get this type of problem its amazing with antivirus escaping....
see coming to our point i installed AVG antivirus in my friend sys they are using dell laptop with high configuration...
but i tried to open desktop icon of AVG its not coming and den i tried to uninstall dt but its not going..
and i was trying to download setup file from net for that i just typed ANTIVIRUS in google browser den 
that browser closed automatically i tried again nd again..... we can use browser for otherpurpose but if you type ANTIVIRUS in anywhere in browser that window automatically closed ..
can anyone of tel me y exactly its happening like that wts d solution for that

Comment: Sounds like you may have a virus that watches what you type into browser and stops you from looking for anti-virus solutions. But this isn't really programming related so I'll nudge it over to superuser.

Comment: what is the solution for that

Comment: @naveensiva, I posted the answer below, if it works please click the accept answer button on my question if it does solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have a virus on your computer that would rather not be uninstalled. If it senses you doing something that could harm it, it will prevent you from doing so.

Restart your computer and when its booting up keep pressing F8 and when you get to boot menu, choose boot in safe mode with networking.

From there you can open your browser and install an antivirus, I recommend [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/), as it is free, lightweight on resources, and is thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably have a virus on the system in question. I think your best course of action is:
1. to install another OS on the system and try running a full scan on all drives. you should avoid opening any of the drives before the scan. also you should format the drive you are going to install your windows in.
2. if you don't need to keep the current OS, just format the drive and install a fresh OS on that drive, then again try running a full scan on all drives.